# "Filtering" or selecting everything below a given tag in XML

Tags: python, xml, xpath

Consider the following XML (which I store in the string variable `data`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">foo</a:Action>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <ns1:RetrieveStoryML_Response_1 xmlns:ns0="http://www.bar.com" xmlns:ns1="http://www.foo.bar">
            <ns1:StoryMLResponse>
                <ns1:STORYML xmlns="http://www.none.com">
                    <HL space="preserve" xmlns:ns3="http://www.foo.foo.foo">
                        <ID>12345</ID>
                        <TE>This is the text I'd really like to get</TE>
                    </HL>
                </ns1:STORYML>
            </ns1:StoryMLResponse>
        </ns1:RetrieveStoryML_Response_1>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I'm trying to get rid of everything that's not contained within the `HL` tag. My expected output is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<HL space="preserve" xmlns:ns3="http://www.foo.foo.foo">
    <ID>12345</ID>
    <TE>This is the text I'd really like to get</TE>
</HL>
```

So I load the data:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.fromstring(data)
```

`root` is now this:

```
<Element '{http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope}Envelope' at 0x000000000BE6D4A8>
```

Then I try using the `findall` method like this, following the [XML Xpath docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#example):

```
root.findall('.//HL')
```

But I'm returned an empty list. How can I effectively filter this XML?

Comment: The `HL` element is in the `http://www.none.com` namespace.  See duplicate link for how to deal with namespaces in XPath.